# "Cannot access memory at address" on array of vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a Graph in C++, and I have almost no code, but I get some weird error. If I just run code, I get `Process finished with exit code 0`, but if I take a look at debugger (specifically, it I try to check my `graph` object), I see `Cannot access memory at address 0x...`.

I am new to C++, so I cannot really get what has given me this error. Also, I almost don't have code yet & these few lines I took from my previous program which worked without this problem.

Anyway, I have a `vertex` class:

```
#ifndef P2_VERTEX_H
#define P2_VERTEX_H

class vertex {
private:
    int id;

public:
    explicit vertex(int id) { this->id = id; }
    int get_id() { return id; }
};

#endif //P2_VERTEX_H
```

And then a `graph` header:

```
#ifndef P2_GRAPH_H
#define P2_GRAPH_H

#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

class graph {
private:
    int N; // number of vertices
    int M; // number of edges
    std::vector<vertex*> vertices; // vector of vertices
    std::vector<vertex*> *adj; // ARRAY of vectors of vertices
public:
    graph(int n_vert);
    graph(bool from_file, const char *file_name);
};
```

with implementation of `graph`:

```
#include "graph.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


graph::graph(int n_vert) {
    N = n_vert;
}
```

And I instantiate `graph` as:

```
#include "graph.h"

int main() {
    graph g = graph(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, I get this mistake if I uncomment `std::vector<vertex*> *adj;` in a graph header. While I realise that this is probably not the perfect way of storing adjacency list, I fail to see why it gives me an error I mentioned. Especially since I used it before, just instead of `std::vector<vertex*>` I had `std::vector<edge*>` where `edge` was some `struct`. I tried also to have `std::vector<vertex>` isntead of `std::vector<vertex*>` but I have the same error.

Upd:
If I initialize `adj` in constructor:
`adj = new std::vector<vertex*>[N];`
I get `Duplicate variable object name` in debugger after reaching this line.

Comment: Unfortunately, because your question fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], that anyone can use to reproduce and then analyze your issue, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. For more information, see [ask] in the [help].

Comment: Your `graph::graph(int n_vert)` constructor should set `adj = nullptr;` too. Otherwise it will point to a random location in memory, and your debugger will hate you. You could use a `vector<vector<vertex*>>` instead, as vectors have a sensible default constructor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am really wondering what you expect there if this actually all the code I have.

Comment: This cannot be "all the code" you have. The shown code fails to include at least one function that's required in every C++ program that can be successfully compiled and executed. Therefore, it cannot logically be a [mre]. If it's "all the code" you have, you will not be able to compile it into an executable format and load it in a debugger, as you've claimed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if `int main()` really helps you to see the issue, I added it to the code.

Comment: @Botje if I add any constructor, after reaching it in the debugger the error changes to `Duplicate variable object name`. I tried with both constructor that I planned to use and with `adj = nullptr`.

Comment: @Valeria It's not about adding a constructor. The error is that you have not initialized your pointer. In the already existing constructors initialization lists, you should set `adj` to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Fareanor sorry, I use the wrong wording. I get the error of `Duplicate variable object name` if I try to add to `graph::graph(int n_vert)` either `adj = new std::vector<vertex*>[N];` or `adj = nullptr`.

Comment: That sounds like a debugger issue more than a program issue. It is the correct solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never initialized `adj` so it will point to a random location in memory.
You have to initialize the pointer to `nullptr` to get rid of it.

For example, in the constructor initialization list:

```
graph::graph(int n_vert) : N(n_vert), adj(nullptr)
{}
```

---

By the way you forgot to initialize other field members.